# Here is our sunroom's dimensions. How many BTUs of a Mitsubishi minisplit AC unit should we get?

Tags: hvac

We live in Pennsylvania, USA.

We have a sunroom extension to the first floor of our main house. No conditioned space below. Walls are drywall and vinyl siding. Unsure about the insulation of the roof.

We spend about 95% of our time in area A so I'd like to prioritize the heating and cooling of area A and if the benefits gets to area B, that's cool but not strictly necessary.

The small rectangle is the proposed location for a mini split Mitsubishi AC.

How many BTUs should I be looking to get and should I go for the hyper heat or is the regular unit okay?

[image]

Comment: Sunroom, but you don't mention any windows, which are a **large** factor in heating and cooling. The direction the presumed windows face also matters, as does whether they are shaded in any way, such as by trees or a roof overhang. It's also not clear how it relates to the house, which walls are interior or exterior, and with no information on the insulation levels anywhere. As for HyperHeat or not, check the low operating temperature against your seasonal lows, and consider if you have another way to get heat to this space on a few very cold nights, or the heat pump must be the only heat.

Comment: You need to provide the height of the ceiling and dimensions of doors and windows. Why not ask for a quote and see what the pros suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it is a sun room, means lots of windows, means poor thermal insulation unless you have dual glazed windows.

Just based on square footage (500) you need approximately 15,000 BTU with 4 windows.

A 1.5 Ton mini split would work,